# yii2 sql запрос

Tags: sql, yii2

Здравствуйте. Делаю добавление в друзья.

Вот таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию, status = 0. Как юзер второй подтвердил, то 1.
user_id тот, кто первый добавил. fried_id кого добавил.
Подскажите, как мне правильно теперь выбрать данные из таблицы, а именно: друзья определенного пользователя.

```
public function actionIndex($id){

    $user = User::findOne($id);
    if(empty($user)){
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Такого пользователя нет!');
    }


    $list_friend = Friend::find()->where(['status' => 1])
    ->andWhere(['friend_id' => $id])
    ->andWhere(['user_id' => $id])
    ->limit(5)
    ->orderBy('RAND()')->all(); // так не правильно...


}
```

user_id - подал заявку на добавление в друзья. friend_id - тот, кого захотел добавить 
Из таблицы видно, что пользователь с id 3 добавил пользователя с id 1. и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер.

```
$list_friend = Friend::find()->where(['status' => 1])
->andWhere(['friend_id' => $id])
->orWhere(['user_id' => $id])
->limit(5)
->orderBy('RAND()')->all();
```

p.s.

> Подскажите, как мне правильно теперь выбрать данные из таблицы, а именно: друзья определенного пользователя.

user_id это тот, чьих друзей Вы хотите получить?
Тогда зачем Вам вообще friend_id?

p.s.s.
У одного пользователя может быть несколько друзей, поэтому hasOne() надо заменить на hasMany();

Так же необходимо было указать наличие связей и описать полностью проблему.

Все подробности можно узнать по [ссылке](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md)

p.s.s.s.
$list_friend->friend->username;

Comment: так вы выбираете только по user_id. Не правильно

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: user_id  - подал заявку на добавление в друзья.
friend_id - тот, кого захотел добавить

Comment: В таком случае дополните свой вопрос. Из него не ясно, что именно Вам нужно.

Comment: добавил дополнение

Comment: user_id подаёт заявку и указывает id тех, кого хочет добавить. Вам надо получить id всех пользователей, кого хочет добавить user_id. Зачем Вам трогать friend_id?

Comment: нет. он перешел на страницу пользователя, например: сайт/cabinet/index?id=7
Подает заявку. и в бд записывается, user_id=1 и friend_id=7 вопрос, как отобразить всех друзей у юзера

Comment: дополнил ответ. orWhere()

Comment: да, так вроде верно. я на самом деле тоже так делал, но тогда возникает проблема, как мне в цикле отобразить имена друзей? я в моделе Friend сделал:    public function  getFriend(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::ClassName(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
но это не совсем работает, т.к. юзер с id 3 два раза добавлял в друзья... и имя с id 3 буде два раза дублироваться

Comment: дополнил ответ. и можете попробовать использовать distinct(). Всё по ссылке в ответе.

Comment: сделал hasMany. и последний вопрос, а как мне отобразить имя из таблицы user? <?php foreach($list_friend as $list_f):?>
 <?= $list_f->friend->username?> - так не работает.

Comment: И не будет работать. дополнил ответ.

Comment: это же в цикле нужно вызывать... $list_friend->friend->username  - я про это.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75737/discussion-between-slo-nik-and-artem55555p).